# How to find the location for having a 50% probability of making a shot

Tags: probability

I'm interested in finding the spot on a court that a player has a 50% probability of making a shot. The probability decreases monotonically, but not linearly, with distance. There are no other factors involved. The player will make almost all the shots within 5 feet of the goal and miss almost all shots from greater than 15 feet from the goal. The player takes about 25 or 30 shots, some within 5, some greater than 15 and some in the 5-15 foot range. How best to estimate the distance at which the player has a 50% probability of making the shot? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have data on makes and misses along with the distances at which shots were attempted?

Comment: Yes, I have the distances of each shot and success or failure.